# Codeception/AspectMock Parent class not found by locator

Tags: php

I have a problem with [Codeception/AspectMock](https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock). 
When using custom autoloader and try to create an instance of a class which has parent form the same custom namespace I have this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Class [parent
>   class name] was not found by locator in
>   vendor/goaop/parser-reflection/src/ReflectionEngine.php:112

I have very simple setup:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$kernel = AspectMock\Kernel::getInstance();
$kernel->init([
    'debug' => true,
    'includePaths' => [__DIR__. '/lib'],
]);
$kernel->loadFile(__DIR__ . '/autoload.php'); // custom autoloader

$b = new \lib\B();
```

Class \lib\B:

```
namespace lib;

class B extends A {}
```

Class \lib\A:

```
namespace lib;

class A
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return static::class;
    }
}
```

Class B is loaded via my custom autoloader, but then the locator tries to load parent class A via composer autoloader and returns this error. Is this a bug, or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I have a similar issue but Im not using a custom loader. All PSR4 and it just does not work.

Answer (score 7):

The topic starter has already got an answer [on GitHub](https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock/issues/117).

> In order to use custom autoloader you should re-init ReflectionEngine with composite class locator that will be able to locate your classes or you can use CallableLocator with closure for resolving paths.
>
> Or, even better you could switch your code base to the PSR0/PSR-4

For example:

```
$kernel->loadFile(__DIR__ . '/autoload.php'); // custom autoloader

\Go\ParserReflection\ReflectionEngine::init(
    new class implements \Go\ParserReflection\LocatorInterface {
        public function locateClass($className) {
            return (new ReflectionClass($className))->getFileName();
        }
     }
);

$b = new \lib\B(); // here you go
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can easily do a find and replace on your codebase, maybe you could refactor your code to PSR-4 autoloading standards and do away with the need for a custom autoloader altogether.

This is the spec https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/. I'll try and explain it as simply as possible.

Imagine changing your lowercase namespace `lib` to `Lib`, and setting that namespace to the `src/` directory in your `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Lib\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

After setting that, run `composer dumpautoload`. Then all you need to do is search and replace `namespace lib;`, replacing with `namespace Lib;`.

An example class located in `src/Form.php` would have `namespace Lib;` at the top, followed by `class Form`.

```
<?php 

namepace Lib;

class Form
{
  // code
}
```

Namespaces use the folder naming convention. All classes directly in `src/` have namespace `Lib;`. If there are subdirectories, the directory name becomes part of the namespace. For example a file in `src/Form/Field/Text.php` would have `namespace Lib\Form\Field; class Text {}`.

```
<?php 

namepace Lib\Form\Field;

class Text
{
  // code
}
```

You can see the full convention in the link above, but the general rule is make any folders  begin with a capital letter, as with your classname, and the autoloader should be able to find all of your classes.

This is probably the best practice solution for you, and again as I said, only requires a little bit of file renaming and namespace tweaking. Good luck!