# Codeception/AspectMock Parent class not found by locator i Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

I'm trying to use [Codeception/AspectMock](https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock) in Yii2 tests.
I have two classes:

One:

```
namespace backend\baseModel;
class BaseModel
{
    public static function getId()
    {
        return 9;
    }
}
```

Second:

```
use \backend\baseModel\BaseModel;

class ModelA extends BaseModel
{
    public static function getId()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

I am trying to test ModelA:

```
class TestModel extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{

    public function testGetId()
    {
        test::double(ModelA::getId(), ['getId' => 7]);
        $this->assertSame(7, ModelA::getId());
    }
}
```

I will do the test with an error:

```
1) TestMode: Get id
 Test  tests/unit/TestModelTest.php:testGetId

  [InvalidArgumentException] Class backend\baseModel\BaseModel was not found by locator

#1  /var/www/vendor/goaop/parser-reflection/src/ReflectionEngine.php:125
#2  /var/www/vendor/goaop/parser-reflection/src/ReflectionEngine.php:140
#3  /var/www/vendor/goaop/parser-reflection/src/ReflectionClass.php:44
#4  /var/www/vendor/goaop/parser-reflection/src/ReflectionClass.php:150
#5  /var/www/vendor/goaop/parser-reflection/src/Traits/ReflectionClassLikeTrait.php:446
#6  /var/www/vendor/goaop/parser-reflection/src/Traits/ReflectionClassLikeTrait.php:924
#7  /var/www/vendor/goaop/parser-reflection/src/Traits/ReflectionClassLikeTrait.php:317
#8  /var/www/vendor/goaop/parser-reflection/src/Traits/ReflectionClassLikeTrait.php:303
#9  /var/www/vendor/goaop/framework/src/Instrument/Transformer/CachingTransformer.php:121
#10 /var/www/vendor/goaop/framework/src/Instrument/Transformer/CachingTransformer.php:78
```

My configuration file:

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'test');
defined('YII_APP_BASE_PATH') or define('YII_APP_BASE_PATH', __DIR__.'/../../');

require_once(YII_APP_BASE_PATH . '/vendor/autoload.php');
$kernel = \AspectMock\Kernel::getInstance();
$kernel->init([
    'debug' => true,
    'cacheDir'     => __DIR__ . '/_data/cache',
    'includePaths' => [__DIR__.'/../../backend'],
]);
$kernel->loadFile(YII_APP_BASE_PATH . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
```

I tried the solution proposed here (in the first answer): 
 [Codeception/AspectMock Parent class not found by locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974091/codeception-aspectmock-parent-class-not-found-by-locator)

The error stops appearing, but then the getId () method returns 5 instead of 7.

Comment: I made a mistake in the line `test :: double (ModelA :: getId (), ['getId' => 7]);`, should be `test :: double (ModelA :: class, ['getId' => 7] ) `. This way they work correctly. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You have static method and you override getId function in ModelA, and in test you are invoking ModelA class, so it should return 5 in you case.