# error "Class was not found by locator" when running tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, goaop

My tests stopped working as soon as I created interface class and implemented it in my User class. Tests throw this error:

```
Class app\models\MyInterface was not found by locator
```

I figured out that `Go\ParserReflection\ReflectionEngine` calls `interface_exists($fullClassName, false)` and this returns false.

Any idea how to fix that?

**EDIT**

I added a functional tests and now it cannot find my BaseController class which i use to extend from.

```
Class app\controllers\BaseController was not found by locator
```

Controllers are not even in my `$kernel->init(['includePaths' => ...])` so I think it should be ignored by goaop?

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you stored that interface at the expected location?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes. Every other class is loaded just fine. When I removed the interface everything works as usual. I wanted my code to be more "type safe" tho. I will have to live without interfaces unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53184822/2655151).
You also could take a look this issue [on Github](https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock/issues/117).